# Paginated data not being displayed in the template Django

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views, django-pagination

I'm sending a query result from my database (combining 3 models) to one of my templates, allowing users to filter the output.
Displaying all the information I want works just fine, until I try to paginate the results. Then I get empty QuerySet and 'Page 1 of 1' underneath.
It completely baffles me as unprocessed set is fetched to the template without any disturbances.

Here's my views.py:

```py
products =Product.objects.all()
out = Sets.objects.filter(
    ItemInSet__item__name__in=Product.objects.filter(metrics=1).values_list('product_name', flat=True)
).exclude(
    ItemInSet__item__name__in=Product.objects.filter(metrics=0).values_list('product_name', flat=True)
).distinct()

page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(out, 10) # show 10 per page
try:
    out_p = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    out_p = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    out_p = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'item_list.html', {'products': products, 'results': out_p})
```

And my template:

```html
<table id="id_item_list" >
{% if results.all  %}
    {% for result in results %}
        <tr>
        <form method="GET">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <ul>
                 <a href="/result/{{result.slug}} class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <h4>{{ result.name|title }}</h4>
                <!-- and few more objects from Sets and ItemInSets etc. -->
                </a>               
            </ul>
        </form>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No Sets matched your criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
</table>
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
    {% if results.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="current">Page {{ results.number }} of {{results.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
    {% if results.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ results.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *results* are empty and pagination shows only *'Page 1 of 1'*. No elements displayed whatsoever. When I pass set without pagination (*out*) it is fine.
Is querying over multiple models causing this problem?
I've seen the approach with itertools, yet combining query is not my immediate problem. Or is it?

Edit:
following instructions provided in comments solved the issue.
I've treated paginated data as a QuerySet, not as a Page, which in turn made me use unsupported method and shown no results, mea culpa.

Comment: i think you should to remove the if condition in the template `if results.all` because the paginator page does not have the method.

Comment: and use the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty to print `No Sets matched your criteria.`

Comment: correct, a `Paginator` page is a `Page` which you can iterate over (like a list), not a `QuerySet`, therefore it doesn't have the method `all()`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#page-objects)

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my misconception. I did not realise it while reading some code snippets I've used as reference. It works now.